# Unauthorizedaccessexcception when copy work item from a team project collection to another

Tags: .net, tfs, workitem

I've a problem when migrate work item between two projects in two separate team project collections like below:

I used TFS SDK to collect work item from source project and copy to target project by **`wi.Save()`** method.

It throw `System.Unauthorizedaccessexcception`** (TF201038:Linked work item does not exist or access is denied. See Work Item Permissions for Links...)

```
InnerException**:System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException-> Failed to modify links. The following linked work items do not exist or access is denied: % LinkFailues=\"-3,273123,...
```

Although it run well if I copy wi between 2 projects in the same team project collection

I think it's a permission error but I can't find any solution available.

Comment: Maybe sharing some code where an exception is thrown would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're supposed to be able to do this.  Certainly it's not supported in the normal interface, but I assume you know this as you're not using that :)

However, according to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsintegration/thread/96a49b98-94b3-40b7-bb54-0e3be83b550b/ it can be done, see his link to his blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2011/10/20/tfs-integration-tools-can-i-migrate-all-work-items-from-one-team-project-collection-to-another.aspx says it can be done

Comment: If so, there're no way to attain it. I've try TFS intergration tools but seem it can't copy work items parent-child query with links, history...